# Scorching Ray - Choosing targets

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

When casting *scorching ray* must the caster choose his targets first and then roll each ray to determine if they hit?  Or, can they choose one target at a time and see the results of the attack and damage before choosing the next target and ray attack?

Example:
Wizard casts scorching ray and there are 3 skeletons.  If the first ray kills the first skeleton can he then aim the other 2 rays at the next one, or does it need to be pre-determined where each ray is going to go?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE. Please take the tour, and visit the help, to find out how to get the most out of a Q&A site. (And you get nice badges if you do! :)  Thanks for the question, and have fun.  [Here's a related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51722/22566).  There's no bad side to asking a question that we later find is a dupe: it is common for two people to ask the same question somewhat differently.